# Return a list with the second youngest people in age Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The idea is to return the second youngest persons from an array Person type.
I have this but don't know if it's the best solution, how do you see that approach? or what would be another good idea to resolve this. Thanks any suggestions

this is the class:

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private Integer edad;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Integer getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Persona(String nombre, Integer edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

and the method to make the return also a list with example values (I just sorted the list and then using a filter quit the people with the first value and then filter with the new first value to save only that values)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Persona> listaPrueba = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona("Patricia", 21));
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona("Juan", 22));
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona( "Ana", 45));
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona("John", 22));
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona( "Max", 21));
        listaPrueba.add(new Persona("Peter", 50));

        segundoMayor(listaPrueba).stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getNombre() + " " +item.getEdad()));
    }

public static List<Persona> segundoMayor(ArrayList<Persona> lista){
        lista.sort(Comparator.comparing(Persona::getEdad));
        List<Persona> listaFiltrada = lista.stream().filter(item -> !item.getEdad().equals(lista.get(0).getEdad())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return listaFiltrada.stream().filter(item -> item.getEdad().equals(listaFiltrada.get(0).getEdad())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

**the output should be:**

**Juan 22
John 22**

Comment: @user16320675 because could be more that one person with that age and the idea is to return all the second youngest

Comment: Using sort to find a max is inefficient.

Comment: already edit the question to be clearer

Comment: Why is age an `Integer`? Do you intend to use `null` when age is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to find the list in a single parse of the array like this

```
public static List<Persona> segundoMayor(List<Persona> lista){
    lista.sort(Comparator.comparing(Persona::getEdad));
    Persona first = lista.get(0), second = null;
    List<Persona> secondRankList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Persona persona: lista) {
        if(second == null && persona.getEdad() > first.getEdad()) {
            second = persona;
        }
        if(second != null && second.getEdad().equals(persona.getEdad())) {
            secondRankList.add(persona);
        } else if(second != null && !second.getEdad().equals(persona.getEdad())){
            break;
        }
    }
    return secondRankList;
}
```

Comment: Note: the loop can terminated if `second != null` and `!second.getEdad().equals(persona.getEdad())`

Comment: @user16320675 good catch. I've updated the answer with this condidition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my Java IDE setup at the moment, so consider this to be pseudo code (and write your own unit tests to check for bugs). But my solution would be to iterate the list of `Persona` objects to find the second-youngest age, then iterate the list again to find all objects with that age. Then you can add matching `Persona` objects to a collection, and/or print them out to the console.

```
int youngestAge = 1000, secondYoungestAge = 1000;
for (Persona p : listaPrueba) {
    int edad = p.getEdad();
    if (edad < youngestAge) {
        secondYoungestAge = youngestAge;
        youngestAge = edad;
    } else if (edad < secondYoungestAge) {
        secondYoungestAge = edad;
    }
}

if (secondYoungestAge == 1000) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No matching Persona!");
}

List<Persona> secondYoungestPersona = new ArrayList<>();
for (Persona p : listaPrueba) {
    int edad = p.getEdad();
    if (edad == secondYoungestAge) {
        secondYoungestPersona.add(p);
        // AND/OR write the name and age to console
        System.out.print(p.getNombre() + " " + edad + " ");
    }
}
```

This ought to be more efficient than using a `TreeMap` (sorted by age) or sorting the entire `ArrayList` (because you don't care about the order of the rest of the items, you just care about the second-youngest items). But if you need to be sure, then carefully write a JMH benchmark to test the three approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Very intresting.
I wrote a solution with streams. Perhaps, it doesn't have the best performance but it has a high readability.

```java
public static List<Persona> segundoMayor(final ArrayList<Persona> lista) {

    // first, sort it by age
    final var sorted = lista
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Persona::getEdad))
            .toList();

    // now, find the second youngest age
    final int secondYoungestAge = sorted
            .stream()
            .map(Persona::getEdad)
            .distinct()
            .skip(1)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(0);

    // at the end: only take the youngest 
    // and second youngest with takeWhile (so we can reduce the iterations)
    // and filter them for the second youngest age
    return sorted
            .stream()
            .takeWhile(persona -> persona.getEdad() <= secondYoungestAge)
            .filter(persona -> persona.getEdad() == secondYoungestAge)
            .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A kind of mostly functional approach:

```java
private static List<Persona> segundoMayor(List<Persona> lista){
    return lista
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Persona::getEdad))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey))
        .map(Entry::getValue)
        .skip(1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());  // or orElse(List.of());
                                           // or orElsehrow();
```

Basically:

- group by age into a `Map<Integer, List<Persona>>`
- sort the groups by age
- extract the `Persona` list for each age
- skip the first list (so the second youngest is next)
- get the first list left on the stream
- if none is available, result in an empty list

Replace `orElse` with `orElseThrow` to throw a `NoSuchElementException` instead of returning an empty list, in the case that the input list does not contain at least two `Persona` with different ages.

This probably is not be the most efficient way: creating maps for all ages, but, on the other side, sorting less elements (one entry per age).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one would use a heap to efficiently find the *n* smallest elements.

- Create a heap with the *reverse* of the desired order (a max heap, in this case).
- For each element,

  - add the element to the heap;
  - if the heap has more than *n* items, remove the top of the heap.

With this approach, if there are more than *n* ties for smallest element, you get the first *n* results that you looked at.

This case is a little different because you want to find an unconstrained number of elements that tie for the *nth* smallest attribute. That requires some extra steps.

First, you can build a general-purpose "top hits" collector for use on with streams:

```java
/**
 * @param limit the maximum number of items to collect
 * @param order a function to establish item ordering
 * @param <T> the type of items to collect
 * @return a collector for a limited number of items ordered <em>last</em>
 */
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> top(int limit, Comparator<? super T> order) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(order);
    Supplier<Queue<T>> supplier = () -> new PriorityQueue<>(order);
    BiConsumer<Queue<T>, T> accumulator = (q, e) -> {
        q.add(e);
        if (q.size() > limit) q.remove();
    };
    BinaryOperator<Queue<T>> combiner = (q1, q2) -> {
        q2.forEach(e -> accumulator.accept(q1, e));
        return q1;
    };
    Function<Queue<T>, List<T>> finisher = q -> {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(q.size());
        while (!q.isEmpty()) list.add(q.remove());
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list;
    };
    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}

/**
 * @param limit the maximum number of items to collect
 * @param order a function to establish item ordering
 * @param <T> the type of items to collect
 * @return a collector for a limited number of items ordered <em>first</em>
 */
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> bottom(int limit, Comparator<? super T> order) {
    return top(limit, order.reversed());
}
```

Now you can apply it to your case, with some extra processing. First, the age of each person is filtered, considering only distinct, non-null values. The second-lowest age, if it exists, is then used as a filter in a second pass over the input.

```java
List<Persona> secondYoungest(Collection<Persona> personas) {
    List<Integer> youngest = personas.stream()
        .map(Persona::getEdad)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .distinct()
        .collect(bottom(2, Integer::compare));
    if (youngest.size() != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second youngest age is undefined");
    }
    Integer age = youngest.get(1);
    return personas.stream()
        .filter(p -> age.equals(p.getEdad()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```